# Openfire client not able to connect at port 5222

Tags: apache-spark, port, openfire, smack

I configure openfire 4.1.1 successfully.But all client is not able to connect on port 5222.(spark,thunderbird)

Here client is successfully connect on port 5223.

on port 5222 error is(thunderbird)

The server doesn't support encryption. but your configuration required it.

I enable all possible encryption on server.

Server port settings as follow
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer.

Port 5222 is already use by another service.It is checked by :

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

found 5222 port is using 1395 process Kill that by

```
sudo kill 1395
```

restart openfire server.
Now all working